# "Erro" ao finalizar a importação do CSV

Tags: php, mysql, html5

Boa tarde,

Criei um código em PHP para ler um .CSV contendo Nome, Email e IP.
O objetivo é consultar a API de Geolocalização do http://ip-api.com/ e me retornar o estado correspondente ao IP "ex:RJ", apos isto é inserido na tabela do banco de dados do estado correspondente.

Bom tudo funciona a API é consultada tenho o retorno, gravo no banco de dados e tudo mais, mas ao final da importação da lista no caso o .CSV me deparo com a seguinte mensagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui vai o código:

1 - este é o index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <!-- Meta tags Obrigatórias -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>Importar Csv</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container mt-3">
            <h2>Upload CSV</h2>
            <p>Arquivo CSV contendo Nome, Email e IP sem cabaçalho!</p>
            <p>A importação pode demorar dependendo da quantidade de consultas de IP que devem ser realizadas, a API suporta 150 requisições a cada 60 segundos então pegue um café e aguarde, Quando a importação terminar uma mensagem será exibida!</p>
            <form action="importar.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <p>Arquivo CSV:</p>
                <div class="custom-file mb-3">
                    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="exampleFormControlFile1" name="file">
                    <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Escolher Arquivo</label>
                </div>


                <div class="mt-3">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <!-- JavaScript (Opcional) -->
        <!-- jQuery primeiro, depois Popper.js, depois Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

2 - aqui está o importar.php

```
<?php    
    //conexãO COM O BANCO DE DADOS
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","","csv");

    //A função mysqli_set_charset () especifica o conjunto de caracteres padrão a ser usado ao enviar dados de e para o servidor de banco de dados.
    mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");

    //A função date_default_timezone_set () define o fuso horário padrão usado por todas as funções de data / hora no script.
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

    //Verificação se o arquivo é csv
    $arquivo = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    $nome = $_FILES["file"]["name"];

    //A função explode () divide uma string em uma matriz.
    $ext = explode(".", $nome);

    //A função end () move o ponteiro interno para e produz o último elemento na matriz.
    $extensao = end($ext);       

    if($extensao != "csv"){
        echo "Extensão inválida";
    }else{
        $objeto = fopen($arquivo, 'r');
            $cont =0;

            while(($dados = fgetcsv($objeto, 1000, ";"))!==FALSE)
            {                
                //contador para saber quantas vezes foi executado o sistema
                $cont = $cont + 1;                  

                $nome = utf8_encode($dados[0]);
                $email = utf8_encode($dados[1]);               
                $ip = utf8_encode($dados[2]);   

                // echo $ip;                

                // Inicializa uma nova sessão e retorna um identificador cURL para uso com as funções curl    
                $ch = curl_init();                

                // Define uma opção no manipulador de sessão cURL fornecido.
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://ip-api.com/json/".$ip); 


                // TRUE para retornar a transferência como uma string do valor de retorno 
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 7);

                // Tempo maximo limite para solicitação
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 7);                

                // Pegue o URL e passe para o navegador
                $content = trim(curl_exec($ch));

                // Fechar o recurso cURL e liberar recursos do sistema
                curl_close($ch);

                $regiao = json_decode($content)->region;

                //concatenação do valor para criar valor de variavel unico para a comparação                
                $state = "state-".strtolower($regiao)."-class";    

                $acre = 'state-ac-class';
                $alagoas = 'state-al-class';                
                $amapa = 'state-ap-class';
                $amazonas = 'state-am-class';
                $bahia = 'state-ba-class';
                $ceara = 'state-ce-class';
                $distrito_federal = 'state-df-class';
                $espirito_santo = 'state-es-class';
                $goias = 'state-go-class';
                $maranhao = 'state-ma-class';
                $mato_grosso = 'state-mt-class';
                $mato_grosso_do_sul = 'state-ms-class';
                $minas_gerais = 'state-mg-class';
                $para = 'state-pa-class';
                $paraiba = 'state-pb-class';
                $parana = 'state-pr-class';
                $pernambuco = 'state-pe-class';
                $piaui = 'state-pi-class';
                $rio_de_janeiro = 'state-rj-class';
                $rio_grande_do_norte = 'state-rn-class';
                $rio_grande_do_sul = 'state-rs-class';
                $rondonia = 'state-ro-class';
                $roraima = 'state-rr-class';
                $santa_catarina = 'state-sc-class';
                $sao_paulo = 'state-sp-class';
                $sergipe = 'state-se-class';
                $tocantins = 'state-to-class';


                if($state == $alagoas){
                    $result = $conn->query("INSERT INTO alagoas(nome, email) VALUES('$nome','$email')");                   
                }
                else if($state == $acre){
                    $result = $conn->query("INSERT INTO acre(nome, email) VALUES('$nome','$email')");
                }
                else if($state == $amapa){
                    $result = $conn->query("INSERT INTO amapa(nome, email) VALUES('$nome','$email')");
                }
                else if($state == $amazonas){
                    $result = $conn->query("INSERT INTO amazonas(nome, email) VALUES('$nome','$email')");
                }
                else if($state == $bahia){
                    $result = $conn->query("INSERT INTO bahia(nome, email) VALUES('$nome','$email')");
                }
                else if($state == $ceara){
                    $result = $conn->query("INSERT INTO ceara(nome, email) VALUES('$nome','$email')");
                }
                else if($state == $distrito_federal){
                    $result = $conn->query("INSERT INTO distrito_federal(nome, email) VALUES('$nome','$email')");
                }
                else if($state == $espirito_santo){
                    $result = $conn->query("INSERT INTO espirito_santo(nome, email) VALUES('$nome','$email')");
                }
                else if($state == $goias){
                    $result = $conn->query("INSERT INTO goias(nome, email) VALUES('$nome','$email')");
                }
                else if($state == $maranhao){
                    $result = $conn->query("INSERT INTO maranhao(nome, email) VALUES('$nome','$email')");
                }
                else if($state == $mato_grosso){
                    $result = $conn->query("INSERT INTO mato_grosso(nome, email) VALUES('$nome','$email')");
                }
                else if($state == $mato_grosso_do_sul){
                    $result = $conn->query("INSERT INTO mato_grosso_do_sul(nome, email) VALUES('$nome','$email')");
                }
                else if($state == $minas_gerais){
                    $result = $conn->query("INSERT INTO minas_gerais(nome, email) VALUES('$nome','$email')");
                }
                else if($state == $para){
                    $result = $conn->query("INSERT INTO para(nome, email) VALUES('$nome','$email')");
                }
                else if($state == $paraiba){
                    $result = $conn->query("INSERT INTO paraiba(nome, email) VALUES('$nome','$email')");
                }
                else if($state == $parana){
                    $result = $conn->query("INSERT INTO parana(nome, email) VALUES('$nome','$email')");
                }                
                else if($state == $pernambuco){
                    $result = $conn->query("INSERT INTO pernambuco(nome, email) VALUES('$nome','$email')");
                }
                else if($state == $piaui){
                    $result = $conn->query("INSERT INTO piaui(nome, email) VALUES('$nome','$email')");
                }
                else if($state == $rio_de_janeiro){
                    $result = $conn->query("INSERT INTO rio_de_janeiro(nome, email) VALUES('$nome','$email')");
                }
                else if($state == $rio_grande_do_norte){
                    $result = $conn->query("INSERT INTO rio_grande_do_norte(nome, email) VALUES('$nome','$email')");
                }
                else if($state == $rio_grande_do_sul){
                    $result = $conn->query("INSERT INTO rio_grande_do_sul(nome, email) VALUES('$nome','$email')");
                }
                else if($state == $rondonia){
                    $result = $conn->query("INSERT INTO rondonia(nome, email) VALUES('$nome','$email')");
                }
                else if($state == $roraima){
                    $result = $conn->query("INSERT INTO roraima(nome, email) VALUES('$nome','$email')");
                }
                else if($state == $santa_catarina){
                    $result = $conn->query("INSERT INTO santa_catarina(nome, email) VALUES('$nome','$email')");
                }
                else if($state == $sao_paulo){
                    $result = $conn->query("INSERT INTO sao_paulo(nome, email) VALUES('$nome','$email')");                    
                }
                else if($state == $sergipe){
                    $result = $conn->query("INSERT INTO sergipe(nome, email) VALUES('$nome','$email')");
                }
                else if($state == $tocantins){
                    $result = $conn->query("INSERT INTO tocantins(nome, email) VALUES('$nome','$email')");
                }else{
                    $result = $conn->query("INSERT INTO semip(nome, email) VALUES('$nome','$email')");
                }



                //Atrasa a execução do programa por um dado número de milionésimos de segundos pois a API só permite 150 consultas por minuto.
                usleep(50000);
            }

            if($result)
                {
                    echo "Dados filtrados e inseridos com sucesso em suas respectivas bases de dados!";
                }else{
                    echo "Erro ao inserir os dados </br>";                                                      
                } 

            //Ao fim da execução mostra a quantia de vezes que foi executado            
            echo "</br>FIM DA EXECUÇÃO DO PROGRAMA, FORAM FEITAS: *".$cont."* CONSULTAS A API!";            
    }    
?>
```

PS: estou testando tudo Localhost

Alguém sabe como posso arrumar isso?

a linha 66 é está aqui mas não estou conseguindo arrumar

```
$regiao = json_decode($content)->region;
```

Comment: Teu $content tem a propriedade da region no retorno, seria bom ver se ele nao vem vazio antes de colocar em algum lugar? If isset, try catch seria bem util aí..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente dessa forma, fiz algumas alterações no fonte, porém a lógica segue a mesma, comentei os pontos críticos.

```
<?php    

    function chamaApi($ip){
        // Inicializa uma nova sessão e retorna um identificador cURL para uso com as funções curl    
        $ch = curl_init();

        // Define uma opção no manipulador de sessão cURL fornecido.
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://ip-api.com/json/".$ip);

        // TRUE para retornar a transferência como uma string do valor de retorno 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 7);

        // Tempo maximo limite para solicitação
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 7);

        if(curl_exec($ch) === false){
            throw new Exception('ERRO AO EXECUTAR CHAMADA VIA CURL');
        }

        // Pegue o URL e passe para o navegador
        $content = trim(curl_exec($ch));
        $details = json_decode($content);
        // var_dump($details);
        if($details->status !== 'success'){
            throw new Exception('ERRO NO RETORNO DA API! STATUS: '.$details->status.' MENSAGEM: '.$details->message.' IP: '.$ip);
        }
        // Fechar o recurso cURL e liberar recursos do sistema
        curl_close($ch);

        return $details;
    }

    // Predefinicao dos nomes das tabelas de acordo com cada sigla
    $aEstadosTabelas = [
        'ac' => 'alagoas',
        'al' => 'acre',
        'ap' => 'amapa',
        'am' => 'amazonas',
        'ba' => 'bahia',
        'ce' => 'ceara',
        'df' => 'distrito_federal',
        'es' => 'espirito_santo',
        'go' => 'goias',
        'ma' => 'maranhao',
        'mt' => 'mato_grosso',
        'ms' => 'mato_grosso_do_sul',
        'mg' => 'minas_gerais',
        'pa' => 'para',
        'pb' => 'paraiba',
        'pr' => 'parana',
        'pe' => 'pernambuco',
        'pi' => 'piaui',
        'rj' => 'rio_de_janeiro',
        'rn' => 'rio_grande_do_norte',
        'rs' => 'rio_grande_do_sul',
        'ro' => 'rondonia',
        'rr' => 'roraima',
        'sc' => 'santa_catarina',
        'sp' => 'sao_paulo'
        'se' => 'sergipe',
        'to' => 'tocantins'
    ];


    //conexãO COM O BANCO DE DADOS
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","","csv");

    //A função mysqli_set_charset () especifica o conjunto de caracteres padrão a ser usado ao enviar dados de e para o servidor de banco de dados.
    mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");

    //A função date_default_timezone_set () define o fuso horário padrão usado por todas as funções de data / hora no script.
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

    //Verificação se o arquivo é csv
    $arquivo = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    $nome = $_FILES["file"]["name"];

    //A função explode () divide uma string em uma matriz.
    $ext = explode(".", $nome);

    //A função end () move o ponteiro interno para e produz o último elemento na matriz.
    $extensao = end($ext);       

    if($extensao != "csv"){
        echo "Extensão inválida";
    }else{
        $objeto = fopen($arquivo, 'r');
        $cont = 0;

        while(($dados = fgetcsv($objeto, 1000, ";"))!==FALSE){                
            $nome = utf8_encode($dados[0]);
            $email = utf8_encode($dados[1]);               
            $ip = utf8_encode($dados[2]);   

            // nao precisa contatenar pra ter um id unico, os estados ja sao unicos kkkkk

            try{
                $content = chamaApi($ip);
                // se precisar concatenar algo pra usar em algum lugar...
            }catch (Exception $e) {
                echo 'Exceção capturada: ',  $e->getMessage(), "<br>";
                continue; // vai pro proximo laco do while , tira pra cair no else a seguir do insert no semip / sem ip ou ip errado cai aqui
            }

            $estado = strtolower($content->region);

            // Verifico se a chave do estado existe no array de tabelas predefinido
            if(array_key_exists($estado, $aEstadosTabelas)){
                $query = "INSERT INTO ".$aEstadosTabelas[$estado]."(nome, email) VALUES('$nome','$email')";
            }else{
                $query = "INSERT INTO semip(nome, email) VALUES('$nome','$email')";
            }

            $result = $conn->query($query);

            if($result){
                echo "IP ".$ip." inserido com sucesso!";
                //contador para saber quantas vezes foi executado com sucesso
                $cont++;
            }else{
                echo "Erro ao inserir os dados.. IP: ".$ip."</br>";
            }

            //Atrasa a execução do programa por um dado número de milionésimos de segundos pois a API só permite 150 consultas por minuto.
            usleep(50000);
        }

        //Ao fim da execução mostra a quantia de vezes que foi executado            
        echo "</br>FIM DA EXECUÇÃO DO PROGRAMA, FORAM FEITAS: *".$cont."* CONSULTAS A API!";            
    }    
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma possibilidade é incluir

```
if ($dados) continue;
```

No inicío do while.

[Notice PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/errorfunc.constants.php)